# Adding events in Shopify?

Tags: events, shopify

Say I want to add "events(event name, event date, event location)" to a Shopify page, what would be the best way of doing that?

1. Blog post does not have options for events.
2. I was thinking of adding it through settings.html. It could work, except I don't know how to add an option to remove an event.  Is there a way?

What you think?

Comment: What do you mean by events? A physical gathering of people, who do stuff together? Do you want them in a list? Or on their own pages? More information would be helpful.

Comment: yes those kind of events.  I do want them in a list that I can add to certain pages. Actually good example is the "upcoming events" yellowish box on the right side of this page. Like that.

Comment: Alright so I have figured it out.  There is no option to remove something in Shopify's theme customization.  Instead, on a page, there would be a logic that shows events if not empty.

Comment: I'm glad you got it figured out! Why don't you post an answer to your question below, so that other people who have the same problem can find your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to my question.

In Shopify theme, I was trying to add a list of social events to a page. The way to do it is add a new fieldset in the settings.html. In the fieldset, you can create tables to hold your form elements like inputs and labels. For eg.

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Add an Event</legend>
  
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <h3 class="heading">Event</h3>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="event_name">Event Name</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="event_name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>  
       <td><label for="event_date">Event Date</label></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="event_date" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>  
      <td><label for="event_location">Event Location</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="event_location" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>  
      <td><label for="event_link_1">Event Link</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="event_link" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
</fieldset>
```

This will insert the "Add an Event" option in your "Customize Themes".  From there, you basically fill in the fields and save.

To show that event on a page, insert the following like this .

```html
<div id="event-name">{{ settings.event_name }}</div>
<div id="event-date">{{ settings.event_date }}</div>
<div id="event-location">{{ settings.event_location }}</div>
<div id="event-link">
   <a href="{{ settings.event_link }}">Event Link</a>
</div>

To not show empty elements, you can use if statement like this.

{% if settings.event_link == blank %} 
{% else %}
<a href="{{ settings.event_link }}">Event Link</a>
{% endif %}
```

This process can be applied to anything else that you want to insert and edit on Shopify pages.